# How to get radio button checked value in Footer Template DataList?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I"m using DataList. in my FooterTemplate I add a radio button I I want check it. but it always return false.

This is my code

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlDelivery" OnItemDataBound="dlDelivery_DataBound"  RepeatColumns="1"  RepeatDirection="Vertical" Width="300" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoDel" GroupName="aaa" OnCheckedChanged="rdoOther_Changed" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" />
        <asp:Label ID="lblDel1"  Text='<%# Eval("Street") %>' runat="server" /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblDel2"  Text='<%# Eval("Suburb") %>' runat="server" /> 

        <span class="clear" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoOther" Text="Other" OnCheckedChanged="rdoOther_Changed" AutoPostBack="true" GroupName="aaa" runat="server" />
    a
    <br class="clear" />

    </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

I check the rdoOther check like this

```
 RadioButton rdoOther = (RadioButton)dlDelivery.Controls[dlDelivery.Controls.Count - 1].Controls[0].FindControl("rdoOther"); 

            if (rdoOther.Checked = true ) // this always fales
{
}
```

How to fix it?

Comment: where you bind data? can you show the binding code? and the condition should be `if (rdoOther.Checked) {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
        foreach (DataListItem item in dlDelivery.Items)
        {
            if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer)
            {
                RadioButton rdoOther = (RadioButton)item.FindControl("rdoOther");

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply search the radio button in e.Item:

```
protected void dlDelivery_DataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton rdoOther = e.Item.FindControl("rdoOther") as RadioButton;

    //rdoOther  will be null if ListItemType is not footer.
    if (rdoOther !=null && rdoOther.Checked)
    {
        // Do your tasks
    }
}
```